# Bootstrap gutter: Where in this example? I am not able to understand where is 30px (gutter) between two column's

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am not able to find where is gutter in bootstrap in between two column's or where is this. I am sure someone should help me out from this issue.

[demo of this](http://codepen.io/gslv/pen/GNPdwL?editors=1010)

One thing more .. can i use two(multiple) class name in jquery `addClass` method? like this:

```
$('.a,.b').addClass('color,font');
<style>
.color{color:red}
.font{font-size:30px}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two(multiple) class name in javascript like this

```
var classes = document.querySelector(".a").className;
classes += " additionalClass";
document.querySelector(".a").className = classes;
```

you can add padding to your bootstrap columns like this

```
[class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```